# How to get the request_token of twitter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, oauth

i want to get oauth_request_token for my application  but when i request for the page of request_token in twitter it is giving me error that "failed to validate to  oauth signature and token".
Please help me in solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

using oauth in objective-c is no minor accomplishment. my advice would be to take a look at [oathconsumer](http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/) and its tutorial. I've used it successfully for oauth and xauth. You may also want to look around for existing twitter oauth obj-c libraries on github and googlecode.